# UIView issue with iPad Air 2. Touches go through, any ideas why this might be?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

So I have a custom UIView class (which I call `UIStageView`) that emulates the look of a prompt in which the background is darkened and its view brought to center (code below). Now, it works perfectly when run on any iPad EXCEPT iPad airs.

For some reason, touch immediately goes through the `UIStageView` and into its parent view. Any reason why this might be? I'm running the project on iOS 8.1 and even when I revert back to 7.1 the bug happens. Note that this problem only happens on iPad Airs (physical and emulator). When run on iPads 1-4, it works.

```
// UIStageView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withTarget:(UIView *)target {
    // Init Background
    CGFloat screenWidth = target.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = target.frame.size.height;
    CGRect rFrame = CGRectMake(0, 10, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rFrame]) {

        [self initSubWithFrame:frame withTarget:(UIView *)target];
        [self initExtension];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        NSLog(@"StageView inited! :)");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initSubWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withTarget:(UIView *)target {
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.8]];

    _properFrame = frame;
    _entranceFrame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y-frame.size.height/2, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    _babyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_entranceFrame];
    [_babyView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    _babyView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    _babyView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [self addSubview:_babyView];

    _target = target;
    _indent = 5;
}
```

Basically, the way my code works is that the `UIStageView` itself becomes relegated to serving as a background while the `_babyView` becomes the main view and is what gets interacted with by the user.
I also have a method set up that removes the `UIStageView` from its parent view when tapped.

This works perfectly on any iPad I've tried (physical and emulator) EXCEPT iPad Airs. Any ideas? :\

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! As it turns out, declaring `@property (nonatomic)float alpha` was causing UIView to malfunction. I noticed my `UIView` wouldn't accept touches at all on either iPad Air or iPad Retina when I didn't explicitly set it (i.e. `_alpha = .5`) and it would fail only on iPad Air when I did set it (i.e. `_alpha = .5`).

EDIT:
Just found out that alpha really is a reserved word and I just never noticed. My bad :\